# Font not changing through UILabel extension

Tags: ios, swift

I have defined some functions in extension of `UILabel` mentioned in the following code:

```
extension UILabel{

    func decreaseFontSize () {
        print("before: \(self.font.pointSize)")
        self.font =  UIFont(name: self.font.fontName, size: self.font.pointSize-10)!
        print("after: \(self.font.pointSize)")
    }

    func setBold () {
        self.font =  UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(15)
    }

    func setSecondaryColor () {
        self.textColor =  UIColor.redColor()
    }


}
```

Now when I call `decreaseFontSize` on the `UILabel` object, I get the expected output in console:

```
before: 17.0
after: 7.0
```

But the font size really doesn't change. Same thing happens with `setBold` function. However, `setSecondaryColor` reflects the changed color.

So how to change the font through extension?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it works well.

[image]

[image]

Haven't you missed anything important? Check my code and may be you find out.

```
import UIKit

class MyCell : UITableViewCell {        
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!        
}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
        cell.myLabel.text = "ABC \(indexPath.row)"
        cell.myLabel.decreaseFontSize()
        return cell
    }
}

extension UILabel{
    func decreaseFontSize () {
        print("before: \(self.font.pointSize)")
        self.font =  UIFont(name: self.font.fontName, size: self.font.pointSize-10)!
        print("after: \(self.font.pointSize)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Using my exact code, you can have get some errors, as I type my code in Swift 3.0...

Answer (score 0):

Calling the code inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews` did the trick.

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

        myLabel.setBold()

    }
```